# How to generate the indices of all elements of a 3D array

Tags: python, numpy

How should I change the below code using numpy **without** using foor loop?

```
# for loop
results = []
for i in range(256):
  for j in range(256):
    for k in range(256):
      results.append([i, j, k])

print(results)
[[  0,   0,   0],
 [  0,   0,   1],
 [  0,   0,   2],
 ...,
 [255, 255, 253],
 [255, 255, 254],
 [255, 255, 255]])
```

Comment: What part are you having trouble with? Installing numpy? Importing it? Creating an array at all? Filling the array? Please share the code showing what you managed to get done so far and be specific about what you're stuck on. StackOverflow can help you solve problems, not write your code for you.

Comment: Based on the edit, sounds like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52838752/filling-3d-array-without-using-loops-in-python) will help.

Comment: note that a list is not a numpy array. For this problem you probably want to use numpy.

Comment: I suggest changing the title to something more specific. E.g. "How to generate the indices of all elements of a 3D array?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the indices of a 256x256x256 (3D) array (without creating it) use [Numpy.indices](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.indices.html):

```
dims = (256, 256, 256)
grid = np.indices(dims)
grid[0]        # row indices
grid[1]        # column indices
grid[2]        # z-axis indices
```

You can reshape these into a 2d array if you want:

```
np.indices(dims).reshape(len(dims), -1).T

array([[  0,   0,   0],
       [  0,   0,   1],
       [  0,   0,   2],
       ...,
       [255, 255, 253],
       [255, 255, 254],
       [255, 255, 255]])
```

Or maybe this is what you are looking for:

```
my_3d_array = np.random.random(dims)
for x in np.nditer(my_3d_array):
    print(x)

0.9550954204220937
0.2571918730243552
0.5651493396119187
0.4984195476733584
0.7378580503708124
... etc
```

If you also want the indices you can use the numpy equivalent of enumerate:

```
for ind, x in np.ndenumerate(my_3d_array):
    print(ind)

(0, 0, 0)
(0, 0, 1)
(0, 0, 2)
(0, 0, 3)
(0, 0, 4)
... etc.
```

Comment: `np.indices((256, 256, 256)).reshape(3, -1).T`, stacking is unnecessary.

Comment: @MechanicPig Thanks. I assumed `np.indices` was a tuple like `np.meshgrid` but you're right, it's an array.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
n = 256
m = 3

result = np.vstack([
    np.tile(np.repeat(np.arange(n), n**(m-e-1)), n**e)
    for e in range(m)
]).T
```

It works with any dimension of your indices. Example with n=3, m=2:

```
array([[0, 0],
       [0, 1],
       [0, 2],
       [1, 0],
       [1, 1],
       [1, 2],
       [2, 0],
       [2, 1],
       [2, 2]])
```

Example with n=2, m=3:

```
array([[0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 1],
       [1, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 1],
       [1, 1, 0],
       [1, 1, 1]])
```

Answer (score 1):

Just discovered another way to do it.

```
dims = (256, 256, 256)
idx = np.stack(
    np.unravel_index(np.arange(np.product(dims)), dims)
).T

array([[  0,   0,   0],
       [  0,   0,   1],
       [  0,   0,   2],
       ...,
       [255, 255, 253],
       [255, 255, 254],
       [255, 255, 255]])
```